# Best Technology suited for building E-Commerce Applications and the review on Supported Frameworks

Tags: asp.net, magento, e-commerce, oscommerce, zoho

This may appear as a subjective question but i am asking from an technical architect point of view.

What would be your choice if you were building E-Commerce based Application to help giant companies carry out their marketing and sales campaigns. I looked into open source frameworks such as Magento that works with ZendFramework using the PHP,MySQL And Apache stack. Other basic frameworks like OSCommerce seem reasonable. Whats the leading E-Commerce framework for .Net Technologies? I also looked into Zoho and it seems like using their applications most of the requirements can be knocked off but I also feel I may face flexibility issues down the line with what they provide.

Please try to mention what architectural benefits do you see in the frameworks you know about. Thanks, as always, and its always great to hear the expert opinions on stackoverflow.

Comment: "...help giant companies carry out their marketing and sales campaigns..."  -- So what is the technological expertise of your development/DBA team?

Comment: Well as of now we dont have DBA expert but have a couple of sharp programmers.

Answer (score 0):

For "Giant companies" your question is formed badly and has no information to actually answer it.

For micro and middle sized companies (10 -500 persons in company) go for Magento EE or Magneto CE version and Magento optimized hosting solution

Comment: Yeah, with Magento EE my only concern was paying $13000 per year sounds expensive. However, using Magento CE and developing other extened features available in EE on my own seems feasible. Is it flexible? Between, pardon my language, by giant companies i implied compainies like ATnT and WallMart. So Scalability and Performance may be a issue down the line.

Comment: what i meant with "your question is formed badly" is that scalability and performance are not the main things to consider when dealing with "giant companies e-stores" as those things depend more on traffic needs and user loads. For giant company $13000 is cheap as hell for enterprise class software